# can we use jdbc if vendor has not provided driver?

Tags: java, jdbc

This is just a theoretical question for my own knowledge. Most of the RDBMS databases that we use have vendor provided JDBC driver but if there is a DB for which vendor has not provided any driver, is it still possible to connect to that database using JDBC? Does that mean that we will have to write our own driver or is there any other way?

Comment: There once was the jdbc:odbc bridge..

Comment: Does you theoretical db integrate with any other api for any programming language?

Comment: Thanks for response !! I don't have a theoretical db, I just wanted to know for my own knowledge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Jan pointed out, there's a `JDBC-ODBC Bridge` that allows you to write JDBC code provided that there's an ODBC driver for the database, if for some reason there doesn't exist a JDBC driver for the database. I remember years ago it being very popular to connect to `MS Access`, but even that's no longer the best way to go.

However being in a situation where you don't have a JDBC driver should be very rare, and if you should encounter that kind of situation, maybe it would be a good time to migrate to a more modern database in any case..

Comment: But: JDBC-ODBC Bridge has been removed with Java 8.

Comment: @Jan There are 3rd party bridges, it's just the Sun implementation that has been removed from the JDK.

Comment: Yes... and this theoretical DB here probably doesn't support ODBC as well ;-)